# Auto-correlation of Random numbers

Tags: simulation, random-variable, autocorrelation

Is saying random numbers are independent equivalent to saying random numbers are auto-correlated in simulation. I am using Auto-correlation method in simulation.

Comment: Don't you mean "not auto-correlated"?

Comment: The sentence "using Auto-correlation method in simulation" does not make sense, can you please rephrase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If random variables are independent then (at the population level) there should be no correlation between them.  The reverse is not true.

So if you take a sequence of samples and treat this as a time series, then there should be no expected autocorrelation.  But since you are looking at a sample rather than the whole population, there is likely to be a measure of autocorrelation in the actual numbers, though some samples may lead to positive autocorrelation and some negative.

You can create autocorrelated random variables from independent random variables, for example by taking a cumulative sum.  So for example with the following R code

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000000
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- cumsum(x)
cor(x[-1],x[-n])
cor(y[-1],y[-n])
plot(y)
```

the sample values of `x` give an autocorrelation of `-0.0004727319` (almost zero) but the sample values of `y` give an autocorrelation of `0.9999838` (almost one).  Most values of `y` are close to their predecessors, as shown in this graph

[image]

Comment: I certainly do not understand the answer: the $y$'s are certainly not identically distributed, so cannot behave as the outcome of a random generator...